# Java - Оптимизация Thread

Tags: java, android

Есть некоторый код,

```
private static SeekBar seekBar;
private static int i = 0;
seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(i = 10; i < 110; i++) {
            try { Thread.sleep(38; }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    seekBar.setProgress(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}.start();
```

В котором с задержкой происходит продвижение (увеличение) seekbar'a.
Можно ли как-то этот метод оптимизировать?

Comment: Использовать [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
private static final int DELAY = 38; // в миллисекундах
private int mProgress = 10;

public void yourMethod() {
    final SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekBar.setProgress(mProgress);
            if (++mProgress < 110) {
                seekBar.postDelayed(this, DELAY);
            }
        }
    }, DELAY);
}
```

Таким образом исчезает надобность в объекте `Thread`, а также объект `Runnable` стал существовать в единственном экземпляре, пока в нём не исчезнет надобность и его не заберёт на тот свет сборщик мусора.